# Rails/Rspec - objects not existing until interacted with

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I have the following code where I create some instances of records using FactoryBot:

```
describe "#force_recalculation_of_lab_container_labs" do
  (1..5).each do |n|
    let("lab_#{n}".to_sym) { create(:lab) }
    let("lab_container_#{n}".to_sym) { create(:skill_path) }
    let("lab_collection_#{n}".to_sym) do
      create(:lab_collection, lab_container: eval("lab_container_#{n}"))
    end
  end
  context 'when adding labs' do
    it "starts with 0 labs" do
      expect(lab_collection_1.labs.count).to eq(0)
    end
    (1..3).each do |n|
      let("lab_collection_inclusion_#{n}") do
        create(:lab_collection_inclusion,
          included_item_id: eval("lab_#{n}").id,
          included_item_type: 'Lab',
          lab_collection_id: eval("lab_collection_1").id,
          subscribed: 0)
      end
    end
    it "updates the lab total correctly after adding labs" do
      binding.pry
    end
  end
end
```

From my pry point, I receive the following:

```
LabCollectionInclusion.count
=> 0

lab_collection_1.lab_collection_inclusions.count
=> 0
```

When I then call a record individually, it appears to then exist:

```
lab_collection_inclusion_1
<LabCollectionInclusion:0x000055a45c985b10
 id: 1,
 included_item_id: 1,
 included_item_type: "Lab",
 lab_collection_id: 4,
 subscribed: false,
 created_at: Thu, 01 Nov 2018 10:48:00 UTC +00:00,
 updated_at: Thu, 01 Nov 2018 10:48:00 UTC +00:00>
```

After which point it exists when searching:

```
LabCollectionInclusion.count
=> 1

lab_collection_1.lab_collection_inclusions.count
=> 1
```

Obviously I don't want to have to do this for every record so my 2 questions are first of all why is this happening, and second of all how to correct it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is expected behavior because [`let`](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/helper-methods/let-and-let) is designed to lazy-evaluated. Quote from the [docs of `let`](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/helper-methods/let-and-let):

> Note that `let` is lazy-evaluated: it is not evaluated until the first time the method it defines is invoked. You can use `let!` to force the method's invocation before each example.

As described in the documentation: Just `let!` (note the `!`) instead of `let` when you need the records to be created without calling them by their name first.

Comment: Thank you - makes sense